# what does $this-> mean?

Tags: php

What is the function of `$this->` operator here? is it point that variable?

Can someone explain the code below:

```
if(isset($this->mDbPort))
{
  $this->mDbHost .= ":" . $this->mDbPort;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`$this->` refers to the object instance.

`$this->mDbPort` refers to the `mDbPort` property of the object this code is a part of.

[PHP Manual :: Objects and Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)